# Get the Height & width of Outmost layer in json

Tags: javascript, json

I need to fetch the **outermost layer's** height and width [600* 600]  from below json dynamically....

```
{
      "path" : " shape\/",
      "info" : {
        "author" : ""   
      },
      "name" : "shape",
      "layers" : [
        {     
          "height" : 600,
          "layers" : [
            {         
              "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
            },
            {         
              "height" : 475,
              "layers" : [
                {

                  "src" : "http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png",             
                  "name" : "mask_image_1"
                },
                {              
                  "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
                }
              ],          
              "name" : "user_image_1"
            }
          ],      
          "width" : 600
        }
      ]
    }
```

So i tried below code , but height and width are not displaying, also there is no console error....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function json(data) {
        var dataObj = {};
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1.width;
        height = layer1.height;

        let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

        for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
            var x = layer2[i].x;
            var y = layer2[i].y;
            var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px");           
        }
    }
    json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready
```

Below is code snippet  :

```js
var mask1;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "vw6ZYre.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "kbXMnVP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };


    function json(data) {
        var dataObj = {};
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1.width;
        height = layer1.height;

        let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

        for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
            var x = layer2[i].x;
            var y = layer2[i].y;
            var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                }
            });

            fileupa1.onchange = function() {
                mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
            };
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
display: flex;
background :gold;
}

.container
{
 border: 1px slolid #DDDDDD; 
display: flex; 
background :silver ;

}


.container canvas {
 display: block;
 
 
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
image 1 
<input id="fileupa1" type="file" >

<div class="container">
</div>
```

There are images inside that layer, but as height and width are not displaying, images are also not displaying, you can test by uploading an image in snippet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layers are arrays

```
    width = layer1[0].width;
    height = layer1[0].height;
```